# 6D RGB D SLAM EFFICIENCY

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How efficient is this [6D RGB-D SLAM](http://wiki.ros.org/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM) in localizing and navigation

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194451/6d-rgb-d-slam-efficiency/) by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-08**:
Check [this paper from authors](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ehess/publications/engelhard11euron/engelhard11euron.pdf), they have resulting model image.Hope it give you and idea. Also the video in wiki page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

6D RGB-D SLAM is a bit more computationally expensive.
ccny_rgbd is comparatively very fast.

Both of these can help in localizing with respect to your initial position or with respect to the reference frame at your starting point.

They can help you in building a 3D map but they are not meant for navigation.

For navigation, you can try using ROS NAVIGATION STACK
You can try to create a 2D map from 3D map (created using previously mentioned methods) and use it with ROS NAVIGATION stack for navigation

Using ccny_rgbd or RGB-D SLAM with a structure sensor may not be a straightforward task.

Firstly, the depth data from the structure sensor should be registered to another external RGB camera, if your structure camera does not provide RGB information.

I would suggest you to use Asus Xtion pro live as it works out of the box with RGB-D SLAM or ccny_rgbd or many other algorithms are out there for RGB-D sensors. Most of these methods need both RGB and depth information for them to work.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-08**:
ccny_rgbd method allows us to create  a map from RGB-D data and localize using visual odometr

Pls provide more details on the differences between this method and 6D RGBD SLAM or [RGBD SLAM](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam_electric/evaluation)

How do I incorporate the ROS navigation stack with SLA

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-08**:
Does the ccn_rgbd use both RGBD and visual odometr

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-10-08**:
yes, it works with rgb-d sensors like kinect and asus xtion pro live

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-08**:
Does it work with the structure sensor as well

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-08**:
How do I combine ccny_rgbd & ROS NAVIGATION STACK

I am using a Parrot Drone with PX4 Autopilot...and [Structure Sensor](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/occipital/structure-sensor-capture-the-world-in-3d?ref=nav_search)
with ODROID-U3  board

How do I connect the ODROID and PX4 - mavros help?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-10-09**:
I have edited the answer. You can have a look at the links given below.
These work with a RGB camera and do not need a structure sensor.
http://wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone
http://vision.in.tum.de/data/software/tum_ardrone

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-09**:
Hi,

the Structure sensor is a RGB-D sensor or just depth sensor

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-10-09**:
I do not know that..i think its just a depth sensor..

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-20**:
May I use Gmapping slam with the structure sensor?